# How do I make sure when I change to different views each is set as the First Responder?

Tags: ios, first-responder

I have an app that uses a tab bar controller with 5 different tabs using one viewcontroller (UIViewController).  On the primary viewcontroller there is an audio function to play audio and when I switch to other views, I am no longer able to use the headset buttons to make adjustments to audio playback (play/stop).  I am told that I need to make each view act as a First Responder so it can receive the notification to adjust audio playback.  How do I do this?

I am only using one UIViewController for the entire app, should I setup different view controllers for each tab of the application instead?

I'm using xCode 4.6.4
iOS SDK 6.1

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details. If you are using a `UITabBarController`, each "view" is a `UIViewController`.

Comment: " I am only using one ViewController for the entire app, should I setup different view controllers for each tab of the application instead?" -- really? You can't put a view in a tab, it has to be a view controller, so I think you're already doing that.

Comment: Yes, I am using UITabBarController and one UIViewController.  In my tab bar I have 5 different "Scenes".  Sorry, I am noob with the terminology here.